# Memory size error when creating unique id using 3 columns

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, unique

I want to create an unique  ID in R based on three columns of serial, pnum and daynum so that they create a unique person-day ID.

I am using a large dataset and the do.call(interaction, df1) produces an error: cannot allocate vector of size 11.1gb.

```
serial         pnum daynum
11011202        1   1
11011202        1   2
11011202        4   1
11011202        4   2
11011203        1   1
11011203        1   2
11011207        1   1
11011207        1   2
11011207        2   1
11011207        2   2
11011209        1   1
11011209        1   2
11011209        2   1
11011209        2   2
```

Any suggestion please?

Comment: Try with `do.call(paste, df1)` or `do.call(interaction, df1)`

Comment: @akrun thanks, I used the do.call(interaction, df1) but I receive the following error Error: cannot allocate vector of size 11.1 Gb

Comment: that means you have a big dataset and have issues in memory

Comment: @akrun I tried memory.size() still not working what else could I try?

Comment: you may need more memory

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What is the larger goal?

Comment: @ sorry for that @Henrik marked as duplicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a hash function is what you are after.
The code below will use package `hashFunction`. It has 3 different hash functions, I have tested with `murmur3.32` that produces 32 bit hashes.

First an example usage with the data in the question..

```
library(hashFunction)

apply(df1, 1, function(x) murmur3.32(paste(x, collapse = "")))
```

Now a larger dataset.

```
serial <- rep(11011200 + 1:1000000, each = 4)
n <- length(serial)
pnum = rep(rep(1:2, each = 2), length.out = n)
daynum <- rep(1:2, length.out = n)

df2 <- data.frame(serial, pnum, daynum)
sum(duplicated(df2))
#[1] 0
```

Tests with the larger `df2`. Matrix access times are faster than df's so I coerce `df2` to matrix..

```
system.time({
  h <- apply(as.matrix(df2), 1, function(x) murmur3.32(paste(x, collapse = "")))
})
#     user    system   elapsed
#   74.199     0.059    74.289
```

Now try to reserve memory first and assign the values in a `for` loop.

```
system.time({
  h2 <- integer(n)
  tmp <- as.matrix(df2)
  for(i in seq_len(n)) 
    h2[i] <- murmur3.32(paste(tmp[i, ], collapse = ""))
  rm(tmp)
})
#     user    system   elapsed
#   67.321     0.045    67.406 

identical(h, h2)
#[1] TRUE

object.size(df2)
#64000984 bytes

object.size(h)
#16000048 bytes
```

The hash vector is 4 times smaller than the dataframe.

**Data.**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
serial         pnum daynum
11011202        1   1
11011202        1   2
11011202        4   1
11011202        4   2
11011203        1   1
11011203        1   2
11011207        1   1
11011207        1   2
11011207        2   1
11011207        2   2
11011209        1   1
11011209        1   2
11011209        2   1
11011209        2   2                  
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: thank you for your help; could you please explain this code serial <- rep(11011200 + 1:1000000, each = 4)

Comment: @RforBegginer It creates a vector `11011200 + 1`, then `11011200 + 2`, etc, each of them repeated 4 times. This seems to be more or less like the example `serial` in the posted question.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using Base R . This will not take up much of your RAM

```
data1 <- read.table(text="serial         pnum daynum
11011202        1   1
11011202        1   2
11011202        4   1
11011202        4   2
11011203        1   1
11011203        1   2
11011207        1   1
11011207        1   2
11011207        2   1
11011207        2   2
11011209        1   1
11011209        1   2
11011209        2   1
11011209        2   2",header = T)


data1$id <- as.integer(factor(with(data1, paste(serial, pnum,daynum))))
```

do try this and let me know the result